# Qt QPSQL driver problem

Tags: c++, windows, qt, postgresql

I'm trying to connect postgresql with Qt SQL module. I successfully compile psql driver(src\plugins\sqldrivers\psql). But when i try to connect postgresql, i get this message;

```
QSqlDatabase: QPSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL3 QMYSQL QODBC3 QODBC QPSQL7 QPSQL
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 8.3, Qt 4.7.1 and Visual Studio 2008 in Windows XP SP3.(I also try [this](http://qtwiki.org/QPSQL_driver_not_loaded_-_unusual_solution), but didn't help)

Comment: Maybe the plugin cannot be loaded due to some other DLL (from postgres) not being found. Have a look at the plugin DLL with dependency walker. Also make sure that your build of psql matches the rest of the Qt build (release vs. debug etc.). You could also try to manually load the plugin with QPluginLoader and see if errorString() tells something useful.

Comment: Frank Osterfeld: i looked plugin dll with dependency walker before. it said ieshims.dll, wer.dll and MSVCR90D.DLL are missing. i downloaded dlls from internet, copied to plugin directory, open with dw("Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module." for wer.dll and ieshims.dll)  but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Did you compile the release and debug versions of the plugin? The output of the dependency walker looks like you work with the debug version. You should have qsqlpsql4.dll and qsqlpsqld4.dll in the %QTDIR%\plugins\sqldrivers directory. You can check the plugin path that is used in your program with: QString QLibraryInfo::location ( QLibraryInfo::PluginsPath );

Comment: i compiled both qsqlpsql4.dll/qsqlpsqld4.dll and plugin path is correct(%QTDIR%\plugins). Thank for the answer.

Comment: The link you mentioned above also talks about the need to have (%pgsql)\bin\ in your path.

Comment: I compiled both release and debug versions, and the plugin path used is correct, yet I am still having the same issue.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Try to use the debug version with VS2008 and have a look at the output window, where all loaded dlls are listed with the full path. Are the paths correct?